# If Spec A is over Spec R, then why A is an R-algebra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> If $\operatorname{Spec}A$ is over $\operatorname{Spec}R$, then why $A$ is an $R$-algebra?

I just don't see why, can somebody explain? Thank you!

Comment: A morphism $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} A \to \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} R$ corresponds to a unique ring morphism $R\to A$ going in the opposite direction, which is precisely your $R$-algebra structure on $A$. The category of affine schemes is isomorphic to the opposite category of the category of commutative rings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the datum of a scheme morphism $f\colon \mathrm{Spec}(A)\to  \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ there belongs a morphism of sheaves of rings $\mathcal{O}_{ \mathrm{Spec}(R)}\to f_*\mathcal{O}_{ \mathrm{Spec}(A)}$ (with some local property irrelevant to the question). Looking at the map on global sections gives the desired ring homomorphism
$$R=\mathcal{O}_{ \mathrm{Spec}(R)}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))\to f_*\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}(\mathrm{Spec}(R))=\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(A)}(\mathrm{Spec}(A))=A.$$ This map provides $A$ with the structure of an $R$-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

Saying "$\operatorname{Spec} A$ is over $\operatorname{Spec} R$" means there's a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} R$. Using the fact that $\operatorname{Spec}$ is a contravariant equivalence of categories between affine schemes and algebras, we see that there is a natural map $R\to A$ here corresponding to the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A\to \operatorname{Spec} R$. This map gives $A$ a natural structure of an $R$-algebra.